# Efficient way to Split text data in R

Tags: regex, r, twitter, split, text-mining

I am working on text mining,
Lets say my data set has the column having the Text data posted in twitter.
e.g
@john Its a fantastic work@lita checkout this is amazing @Amy great App

I want to check to split this to   @john Its a fantastic work, @lita checkout this is amazing, @Amy great App

then i want to see who has posted originally and who has re-posted.

P.S: I am facing another problem while installing the 'sna' package in R, as it showing no such package.

Comment: Package `sna` exists: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sna/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
 strsplit(str1, '(?<=[^@]) ?(?=@)', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "@john Its a fantastic work"     "@lita checkout this is amazing"
#[3] "@Amy great App"
```

#### data

```
str1 <-  "@john Its a fantastic work@lita checkout this is amazing @Amy great App"
```

Comment: Its working for a string only not on the whole variable having such texts
 strsplit(Dataset$text, '(?<=[^@])(?=@)', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
@akrun

Comment: @AmarjeetSahoo,  Can you remove the `[[1]]` and see if you can get output in a list

Comment: Already done getting this error
**Error in strsplit(dataset$text, "(?<=[^@])(?=@)", perl = TRUE) : 
  non-character argument**

Comment: @AmarjeetSahoo  I guess your column is a factor.  Try `strsplit(as.character(Dataset$text), ...)`